# rotation based on center of UIView is not working?

Tags: iphone, ipad

hi i have coded in applicationdidfinish method as

```
  [m_tabViewController view].frame = CGRectMake(0,15, 768, 90);
[m_tabViewController view].center = CGPointMake(670, 0);
[m_tabViewController view].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(315));
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window addSubview:[m_tabViewController view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but after rotation , the width and height of that [m_tabViewController view] is changed(very samll size)..please give solution...center is not working also...

Answer (score 0):

As a first point, this looks odd:

```
[m_tabViewController view].center = CGPointMake(670, 0);
```

I would have thought that the center would have been:

```
x = (0 + 768) / 2 = 384
y = (15 + 90) / 2 = 52.5
```

So I expect the center to be:

```
[m_tabViewController view].center = CGPointMake(384, 52.5);
```

Also, as a second point, the following has me curious.

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[window addSubview:[m_tabViewController view]];
```

As I'm not really sure if this is your intent. Did you really mean?

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[viewController.view addSubview:[m_tabViewController view]];
```

(But that last point is a wild guess.)